# Extra padding in CSS between IMGs

Tags: css

I'm having trouble with extra padding (4px) between two IMG tags. This occurs in Firefox 7.0.1, Safari 5.1.1, Chrome 11.0.696.68, and Opera 10.53 on a Mac (Snow Leopard).

I have uploaded the example here:
http://husnoo.com/img_extra_space/img_extra_space.html

With a screenshot of what it looks like:
http://husnoo.com/img_extra_space/shot.png

The 4 pixels between the two IMGs shouldn't be there.

Thanks!

Nawal.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title here</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        toolbar {
            background-color: #ddd;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
        }

        #tool1 {
            background-color: #0dc;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
        }

        #tool2 {
            background-color: #6dc;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <img id="tool1" src="select.png">
        <img id="tool2" src="transform_move.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't break lines between images instead of

```
<img id="tool1" src="select.png">
<img id="tool2" src="transform_move.png">
```

do

```
<img id="tool1" src="select.png"><img id="tool2" src="transform_move.png">
```

Comment: Thanks! That does it! Out of interest....Why? (I'll accept it in 10mins, apparently I can't accept it before then).

Comment: @Nawal: Line breaks are converted to a space when rendering the HTML, so it's like having `<img /> <img />` when you want `<img /><img />`.

Comment: "\n" char is treated as withe space

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the space between the two img tags.

Or you can add `display:block;` to them and `float:left;`

Comment: then you would need much more css to fix other issues. Bad idea

Comment: depending on what you are trying to achieve it could even be easier. But in any case, not that much css.